post deleteMany/deleteOne middleware not being called mongoose
So, I'm trying to delete many documents at once, and for some reason, the post middleware works for document.deleteOne(), but not for Model.deleteMany(). Specifically, I am looking for a fix for it not firing for Lecture.deleteMany(...) and Chapter.deleteMany(...). Note that the documents themselves do end up being deleted.
Here is the response handler for one of my routes:
export const DELETE = catchAsync(async function (req, { params }) {
  // Check if course exists
  const course = await Course.findById(params.id).populate({
    path: "chapters",
    select: { id: 1 },
  });
  if (!course)
    return new AppError("No courses found with the provided id", 404);

  const { chapters } = course;
  const chapterIds = chapters.map((chapter) => chapter.id);

  // Delete course's lectures
  await Lecture.deleteMany({ chapter: { $in: chapterIds } });

  // Delete course's chapters
  await Chapter.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: chapterIds } }); // Specifically this one

  // Delete course
  await course.deleteOne();
});

And here is the post middleware in my chapter model file (very similar to lecture):
chapterSchema.post(
  ["deleteOne", "deleteMany"],
  { document: true },
  async function (doc, next) {
    console.log("POST DELETE ONE CHAPTER");

    const course = await Course.findById(this.course);

    // Find and remove chapter from course
    const index = course.chapters.findIndex((ch) => ch._id === doc._id);
    course.chapters.splice(index, 1);
    await course.save();

    next();
  }
);


You can loop through each document that you want to delete and call delete.One method.

Yes, but in the general case, I may need to use deleteMany later on, and I want to know why it is not working. Also, looping is less efficient.

In that case, maybe you need to change the middleware to pre instead of post. What I found is pre middleware for deleteMany you retrieve the IDs to be deleted and store them. And in post middleware for deleteMany you use store IDs and later remove them.

I did pre middleware before, but I ran into code issues so I stopped. Maybe I should reconsider. But if you, or anyone knows why this isn't working (maybe I'm making some mistake) just let me know.

Please post your schema for Lecture and Chapter and Course. The Model.deleteMany is the correct option to take. Looping through and deleting one by one is not good option.

I figured it out. I believe post is a document middleware, and since Model.deleteMany() is a query, the middleware does not get called. I changed my code the one below.
chapterSchema.post("deleteOne", { document: true }, async function (doc, next) {
  console.log("Removing chapter from its course");

  // Find course
  const course = await Course.findById(doc.course);
  if (!course) return next();

  // Find and remove chapter from course
  const index = course.chapters.findIndex((ch) => ch._id === doc._id);
  course.chapters.splice(index, 1);
  await course.save();

  next();
});


Please review the below statements. Does it have room to refactor?
const course = await Course.findById(params.id).populate({ path: "chapters", select: { id: 1 }, }); if (!course) return new AppError("No courses found with the provided id", 404); const { chapters } = course; const chapterIds = chapters.map((chapter) => chapter.id); ...

...First of all, Course is found, and Chapters populated. Then the Chapters destructured. And finally, Chapters mapped into ChapterId. Please remember ChapterId is already available in the first statement itself. It means if the first line is refactored as this: const course = await Course.findById(params.id); Then Chapter can get as this: const chapters = course.chapters;
